# Jaxb marshalling strips out a required tag

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, marshalling

I'm trying to produce the following xml output snippet :

```
<benefits>
   <notes>benefits note</notes>
   <detail xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      **<body>**
        <p style="font-family:'Myriad Pro';text-decoration:none">Description 2</p>
      **</body>**   
    </detail>
</benefits>
```

Here is my Xml annotated class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "descriptionType", propOrder = {
    "notes",
    "detail"
})
public class DescriptionType {

    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected String notes;
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(value=CDATAAdapter.class)
    @XmlElement(required = true)
    protected Object detail;

    public String getNotes() {
        return notes;
    }

    public void setNotes(String value) {
        this.notes = value;
    }
    public Object getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }
    public void setDetail(Object value) {
        this.detail = value;
    }
}
```

If a put a breakpoint just before the marshalling and inspect the "detail" variable instance of the class DescriptionType it contains the following

```
String type
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?><body xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><p style="font-family:'Myriad Pro'">Description 1</p>
                        </body>"
```

That when I try marshal back to xml I convert to Document Element in my custom Adapter like so:

```
 Element e =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().
           parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(((String)s).getBytes())).getDocumentElement();
   return e;
```

The output then becomes:

```
<benefits>
   <notes>benefits note</notes>
   <detail xmlns:ns2="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
       <p style="font-family:'Myriad Pro';text-decoration:none">Description 2</p>
   </detail>
</benefits>
```

The question? How can I make it preserve the  tag? 
Thanks so much

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: What is the source of the class producing the object you set in the detail field?